# @JsonTypeName equivalent for XML

Tags: java, xml, json, jaxb

I have some pojos that can be used to return XML or JSON.  The following code works as expected but I would like to avoid mixing/matching jackson annotations with xml annotations.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="MySpecificName")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonTypeName("MySpecificName")
public class Bar{
 @XmlElement
 @JsonProperty
 private String name;
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class BarWrapper{
 @XmlElement
 @JsonProperty
 private Collection<Bar> bars;
}
```

When the above code is run, I get the following JSON:

```
{"bars":["MySpecificName":{"name":"blah"}]}
```

If I comment out the jackson annotations I get the incorrect result of:

```
{"bars":[{"name":"blah"}]}
```

Is there a way (using only XML annotations) to preserve the JsonTypeName value in the JSON output?

Comment: What's wrong with mixing both annotations?

Comment: It gets excessive with lots of classes and fields.  If it can be done in one, it is much simpler and leaves less room for errors. Additionally I'd like to take advantage of the defaultvalues that the XML annotations provide for both XML and JSON

Comment: You could use Moxy http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/03/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider_15.html

Comment: I was hoping to do this out-of-the-box with the XML annotations provided by Java.